# Blender App for iPad os

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am sure this has probably been asked many times over in different ways over the years.

However with the new iPad Os are there any plays to port or create a cut down iPad version of blender?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the official developer forum and not on Blender Stack Exchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation and not about using Blender

Comment: There isn't an iPad-compatible app of Blender.